# Populate the grand total value base on value of each input fields

Tags: javascript

I would like to calculate and populate the grand total automatically before submiting the form. The grand total will base on my 5 input fields.

```
<input type="number" name="inspection_fee">
<input type="number" name="storage_fee">
<input type="number" name="local_fee">
<input type="number" name="cert_fee">
<input type="number" name="others_fee">

<input type="number" name="total_fee">
```

I know how to do it the php way like it would put variables after I submit it then calculate it totally like this.

```
<?php
$inspection_fee = $paymentSettings->inspection_fee;
$storage_fee = $paymentSettings->storage_fee;
$cert_fee = $paymentSettings->cert_fee;
$local_fee = $paymentSettings->local_fee;
$others_fee = $paymentSettings->others_fee;

$total_fee = $inspection_fee + $storage_fee + $cert_fee + $local_fee + $others_fee;
?>
```

But how would I populate the total before submiting it using javascript? Like if I change the inspection fee the total fee will auto adjust depends on the total value.
Looking for help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach onblur event to all input fields to call a JavaScript function. I have changed the "name" attribute to "id" attribute to be used in the JS function.

```
        <input type="number" id="inspection_fee" onblur="calculateTotalFee();">
        <input type="number" id="storage_fee" onblur="calculateTotalFee();">
        <input type="number" id="local_fee" onblur="calculateTotalFee();">
        <input type="number" id="cert_fee" onblur="calculateTotalFee();">
        <input type="number" id="others_fee" onblur="calculateTotalFee();">
        <br/>
        <input type="number" id="total_fee">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function calculateTotalFee(){
                var totalFee = 0;
                var inspectionFee = document.getElementById("inspection_fee").value.trim() === "" ? 0 : 
                    document.getElementById("inspection_fee").value.trim();
                var storageFee = document.getElementById("storage_fee").value.trim() === "" ? 0 :
                    document.getElementById("storage_fee").value.trim();
                var localFee = document.getElementById("local_fee").value.trim() === "" ? 0 :
                    document.getElementById("local_fee").value.trim();
                var certFee = document.getElementById("cert_fee").value.trim() === "" ? 0 :
                    document.getElementById("cert_fee").value.trim();
                var othersFee = document.getElementById("others_fee").value.trim() === "" ? 0 :
                    document.getElementById("others_fee").value.trim();

                totalFee = parseInt(inspectionFee) + parseInt(storageFee) + 
                        parseInt(storageFee) + parseInt(localFee) + parseInt(certFee) + parseInt(othersFee);

                document.getElementById("total_fee").value = totalFee;
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: This produces `NaN` for me when any of the input values are empty

Comment: Updated code to check for blank values. If the input field value is blank, then the value 0 is taken.

Answer (score 5):

1. Set the total input field to read-only
2. Create a function to add up all the inputs and set the value in `total_fee` (good opportunity to use `Array.prototype.reduce`)
3. Bind your function to the inputs `input` event

```js
const inputs = ['inspection_fee', 'storage_fee', 'local_fee', 'cert_fee', 'others_fee']
const total = document.querySelector('input[name="total_fee"]')

const sumTotal = () => {
  total.value = inputs.reduce((sum, input) =>
    sum += parseInt(document.querySelector(`input[name="${input}"]`).value || 0, 10), 0)
}

inputs.forEach(input => {
    document.querySelector(`input[name="${input}"]`).addEventListener('input', sumTotal, false)
})
```

```html
<input type="number" name="inspection_fee">
<input type="number" name="storage_fee">
<input type="number" name="local_fee">
<input type="number" name="cert_fee">
<input type="number" name="others_fee">

<input type="number" name="total_fee" readonly>
```